# Need dataset for forecasting in R

Tags: r, algorithm, dataset, prediction, forecasting

I need a non time-series dataset for evaluating various forecasting techniques in R. Please help me find a suitable dataset. I can't find any. The requirements are: one dependent variable and at least 4 continuous independent variables no factor or binary columns. Please help me out if you have such data.

Comment: Hey! Stackoverflow is a forum for programming questions, which this one is not. Your question is better suited at maybe reddit or kaggle.com. Hence, I am voting to close this question.

Answer (score 1):

You could make one yourself:

```r
var1 <- runif(100, 10, 100)
var2 <- rnorm(100, 20, 3)
var3 <- runif(100, 0.1, 0.9)
var4 <- rnorm(100, 1000, 2000)

odds <- (var1 + var2 + 50 * var3 + var4 / 100)/100

dv <- rbinom(100, 1, odds/(1 + odds))

df <- data.frame(dv, var1, var2, var3, var4)
```

Comment: This R-based web application may help some of the audience here: https://github.com/pablobernabeu/Experimental-data-simulation